# Bijection between NP-complete problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-complete

If $A$ and $B$ are NP-complete problems, is there a *bijective* function $f$ (computable in polynomial time) such that $w\in A$ iff $f(w)\in B$?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I am not the author of the downvote, but the answer to your question is not known and is called the [Berman-Hartmanis conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berman–Hartmanis_conjecture).

Comment: Actually, the Berman–Hartmanis conjecture is stronger: it also requires the inverse of $f$ to be polynomial-time. Nevertheless, I’d be surprised if the answer is known even to the weaker form of question.

Comment: Suppose sparse NP-complete languages exist (i.e. only polynomially many yes instances per input size). Then you could set $B$ to a sparse language, $A$ to a non-sparse language, and no function $f$ would exist. It is wide open (and stronger than P $\neq$ NP) whether sparse NP-complete languages exist.

Comment: @Lopsy: If a sparse $\mathsf{NP}$-complete language exists, then $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$... Exactly the line of reasoning you use is one of the major motivations for looking at sparsity in the first place (going back to Berman-Hartmanis).

Comment: In light of Emil Jeřábek’s comment, I am more interested in whether this statement is equivalent to the Berman–Hartmanis conjecture or there is some evidence that this statement is strictly weaker.